# Sorting an array of pointers to structs inside a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I have an array of pointers to structs inside an array of struct and I want to sort my 'graph[]' by its letters.

My problem was to sort the '*vertexes[]' inside 'struct vertex'. Now I can't show the 'letter' in each pointer inside '*vertexes[]'...

Here's the code with PaulMcKenzie corrections:

```
#include <algorithm> //std::sort()
#include <cstdio> //std::scanf(), std::putchar()
//
struct vertex {
    vertex *vertexes[26];
    vertex **end; //Do the same as 'size'
    unsigned int size;
    char letter;
    void insert(vertex *dest) { vertexes[size] = dest; ++size; /* or *end = dest; end+=1; */ }
    bool empty(void) const { return(this->size == 0); /* or return(vertexes == end); */ }
};
//
bool byLetter(const vertex *A, const vertex &B)
{
    return(A->letra < B->letra);
}
//
int main(void)
{
  unsigned int n(0), N, A, v, V;
  char ini, fim;
  vertex graph[26]; //Each one represents a letter of the alphabet
  std::scanf("%u ", &N);
  while(n++ < N) {
    for(v = 0; v < 26; ++v) {
      graph[v].size = 0;
      graph[v].end = graph[v].vertexes;
      graph[v].letter = v+'a';
    }
    std::scanf("%u %u ", &V, &A);
    do {
      std::scanf("%c %c ", &ini, &fim);
      graph[ini-'a'].insert(&graph[fim-'a']);
    } while(--A != 0);
    for(v = 0; v < V; ++v) {
      if(!graph[v].empty()) {
          std::sort(graph[v].vertexes, &graph[v].vertexes[graph[v].size], byLetter);
          //Not sure why graph[v] + size is more safe then this...
          graph[v].show(); //Problem here
      }
    }
    std::putchar('\n');
  }
  return(0);
}
//
void vertex::show(void)
{
  vertex **p(vertexes); //'p' iterates thought vertexes 
  while(p != end) { //but I can't access the letter in each pointer 
    std::putchar(*(*p->vertexes->letter)); // problem here
    std::putchar(',');
    p+=1;
   }
}
//
```

Comment: `struct vertex *vertexes[26];` Using `struct` in this context is a sign that you're reading `C` material and not `C++` material.  There is no need for `struct` in this context in C++.

Comment: `std::sort(vertexes, &vertexes[size], byLetter)` should be `std::sort(vertexes, vertexes + size, byLetter);`, `vertexes[size]` is an access violation waiting to happen! the same goes for `&graph[i].vertexes[graph[i].tam]`

Comment: `*A->vertexes->letter` is trying to dereference the pointer `A->vertexes->letter`, which doesn't even compile!

Comment: What is tam ? Is it `graph::sort(void)` or `vertex::sort(void)` ?

Comment: I gave an answer, but you should clarify exactly what you are trying to sort.  You have a graph array defined in `main`, so are you trying to sort the `graph` array by character?

Comment: Thanks, I was lost in all those pointers... it worked! :D
Using or not the word struct matter? I mean in the .exe
Why the vertexes + size more safe than &vertexes[size]?;
Each vertex contains a letter of the alphabet, the 'vertexes[]' are  not inserted in order, so I have to sort.
I forgot to translate 'tam' into 'size' in that line...

Answer (score 1):

First, the std::sort is simple.  You give it the starting entry, and the ending entry.

```
    std::sort(graph[i].vertexes, graph[i].vertexes + 26, byLetter);
```

There are 26 `vertexes`, so it is as simple as just adding 26 to get to the last one.

The next issue is that since `vertexes` is an array of pointers, then the function `byLetter` is going to be passed two pointers to `vertex`, not two references:

```
bool byLetter(const vertex *A, const vertex *B)
{
    return(A->letter < B->letter);
}
```

Putting it all together, and removing the C-ism of putting `struct` all over the place, here is a simple version of your program:

```
#include <algorithm> 

struct vertex {
    vertex *vertexes[26];
    unsigned int size;
    char letter;
    void sort(void);
};

bool byLetter(const vertex *A, const vertex *B)
{
    return(A->letter < B->letter);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int i;
    vertex graph[26];
    for(i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
        std::sort(graph[i].vertexes, graph[i].vertexes + 26, byLetter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to mention that that `std::sort()` isn't doing anything and probably has UB for accessing the address of an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Yes, but I was focusing on the compilation error.  I just asked the OP for clarification of what he is trying to sort.